# Split string in list with condition Python

Tags: python-3.x, string

I need to split string in this format:

```
string = "NAMEpaulAGEtwenty"

output = ["NAME", "paul", "AGE", "twenty"]
```

I need to do this **without REGEX or any libraries to import**.
Here's what I tried (and work) but I would like to know if there's something better (both for cyclomatic complexity and time of execution):

```
def split_row(row):
      tmp_upper = ''
      tmp_lower = ''
      row_splitted = []
      for i in range(len(row)-1):
          value = row[i]
          if row[i].isupperper():
            tmp_upper += value
            if row[i+1].islower():
                row_splitted.append(tmp_upper)
                tmp_upper = ''
          else:
            tmp_lower += value
            if row[i+1].isupperper():
                row_splitted.append(tmp_lower)
                tmp_lower = ''
      tmp_lower += row[i+1]
      row_splitted.append(tmp_lower)
      return row_splitted
```

Comment: Why can you not use regexes?

Answer (score 1):

```
def split(s):
    return [''.join(group) for _, group in groupby(s, str.isupper)]
```

1. Strings are iterable, it's a list of chars.
2. We group the string on whether a sequence of chars are upper or not.
3. We then recombine to get a list of strings.

A table of runtimes using `python -m timeit` for the solutions thus far:

```
split(s)
100000 loops, best of 5: 1.49 usec per loop

alt_split(s)
100000 loops, best of 5: 1.39 usec per loop

split_row(row)
100000 loops, best of 5: 2.63 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

For a general case, where you need to split a string based on Uppercase and lowercase letters:

```
def alt_split(s):
    rslt = []
    ss = ''
    upFlg = True
    for i in s:
        print(i, upFlg, ss, rslt)
        if i.isupper():
            if upFlg:
                ss += i
            else:
                rslt.append(ss)
                ss = i
                upFlg = True
        else:
            if upFlg:
                rslt.append(ss)
                ss = i
                upFlg = False
            else:
                ss += i
    if ss:
        rslt.append(ss)
    return rslt
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the following:

```
def split_string(s):
    mk1 = 'NAME'
    mk2 = "AGE"
    pt1 = s.find(mk2)
    pt2 = pt1 + len(mk2)
    return [mk1, s[pt1-len(mk1):pt1], mk2, s[pt2:]]
```

Comment: This only works for the case described, but not in the general case.

Comment: I am not OP. The problem is to seperate upper case sections from lower case sections in a given string. The problem is clear.